# Identify CRS in raster file

Tags: r, geospatial, r-raster

I would like to identify the correct coordinate reference system for the following [ASCII raster file](ftp://ftp.pbl.nl/../hyde/hyde3.2/baseline/zip/0AD_lu.zip):

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 9331200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0833333, 0.0833333  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 179.9999, -90, 89.99993  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : C:/popc_0AD.asc 
names       : popc_0AD
```

I tried to guess the correct projection by setting the CRS to some of the common formats and plotting it, as suggested in related posts. But I am still not sure about the correct setting. As far as I am concerned `raster` and related packages do not entail any function able to estimate missing CRS information. Do you have any idea what this raster file's CRS could be or how to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extent suggests coordinates are not projected. This seems to be the extent of Earth in degrees.
 Then, you may want to use EPSG 4326, which is also `crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"`:

```r
library(raster)

r <- raster("0AD_lu/cropland0AD.asc")
projection(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

However, it is much better to use dataset correctly built with the coordinates reference system. It is never recommended to guess it... But I know that having clean metadata is not always possible...

Comment: Thanks, this certainly answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
r <- raster(nrow=2160, ncol=4320, xmn=-180, xmx=179.9999, ymn=-90, ymx=89.99993, crs=NA)
```

Sébastien Rochette already pointed out that this is surely lon/lat and that you can set the CRS to relfect that

```
crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
```

It seems to me that the extent is a bit suspect. It looks like it is supposed to be a global raster, but that there has been some loss of precision. If so, you may correct that like this:

```
extent(r) <- c(-180, 180, -90, 90)
```

To get

```
r
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 2160, 4320, 9331200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not know why the extent is a bit off, but your suggested correction is certainly a valuable idea that I will add to my code.

Comment: I suspect that the file stores the spatial resolution as `0.0833333`. And then you get: `180 + 4320 * 0.0833333` = 179.9999 and `-90 + 2160 * 0.0833333` = 89.99993